# OpenCV, OpenBR or OpenFace for a large dataset?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition, openfaces

I have been given a task to create a project for recognizing faces from a company database, so I decided to implement the LBP algorithm using python for this. I looked through the available implementations and came across the three libraries. Unlike other questions that I came across which are striving for speed, my main goal is to have as much accuracy as possible in the results regardless of the time taken. Which of these three libraries should I go for to achieve most accuracy, when given that my photos may be blurred, or have posing and illumination issues or a mix of all three?

Comment: you should check out dlib version 19 as well

Comment: dlib is not getting installed in my system due to CMake issues. I am currently trying to resolve the issue.